# How to get the next sequential number with different prefixes?

Tags: excel, vba

I am making an automatic Product SKU creator Excel table. I have a problem: The program makes an SKU depending on options selected from a drop down list and adds one number per list item selected. I have managed to get that working, but the last 4 digits in SKUs are a unique number for each item. Creating the unique numbers is where I have problems. I have SKUs listed like this in a table

[image: Picture]

The program adds new a SKU at the bottom of the table. After the selections from the lists there are the five numbers, for example `01123`. The program should check what is the next "free" sequential number within the numbers that start with the same 5 digits. Like there is `011230001` already and the next SKU would be automatically associated to `011230002` and if there is `011330001` already it would be automatically associated to `011330002`. So each item has unique SKU. How I do that?

Code to get first two numbers:

```
Sub kopioi1()
If Range("A2") = "Tietokoneet" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "01"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Komponentit" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "02"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Oheislaite" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "03"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Ohjelmisto" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "04"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Verkko" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "05"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Mobiililaite" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "06"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Tarvikkeet" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "07"
 ElseIf Range("A2") = "Palvelu" Then
    eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = "08"
End If
End Sub
```

Third number:

```
Sub kopioi2()
If Range("B2") = "Kannettavat" Then
Cells.Find(What:="01", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "1"

 ElseIf Range("B2") = "Pöytäkoneet" Then
Cells.Find(What:="01", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "2"

 ElseIf Range("B2") = "Käytetyt" Then
Cells.Find(What:="01", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "3"

End If
End Sub
```

Fourth number:

```
Sub kopioi3()
If Range("C2") = "_13" Then
Cells.Find(What:="011", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "1"

 ElseIf Range("C2") = "_14" Then
Cells.Find(What:="011", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "2"

 ElseIf Range("C2") = "_15.6" Then
Cells.Find(What:="011", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "3"

 ElseIf Range("C2") = "_17" Then
Cells.Find(What:="011", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "4"

 ElseIf Range("C2") = "Yrityskannettavat" Then
Cells.Find(What:="011", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "5"

End If
End Sub
```

Fifth number and the last four digits:

```
Sub kopioi4()
Dim cell As Range
Dim bottomA As Integer
Dim data_text As String

bottomA = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & bottomA)
If Range("D2") = "Acer" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "1"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "Apple" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "2"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "ASUS" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "3"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "Fujitsu" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "4"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "HP" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "5"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "Lenovo" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "6"
        End If
    Next cell

 ElseIf Range("D2") = "Samsung" Then
    For Each cell In rng
        If Len(cell) = 4 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & "7"
        End If
    Next cell
End If

Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
data_text = ActiveCell.Value

        Cells.Find(What:=data_text, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "3"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rngT As Range
    Dim s, s2, s3, s4
    Dim n As Long

    Select Case Range("a2")
        Case "Tietokoneet"
            s = "01"
        Case "Komponentit"
            s = "02"
        Case "Oheislaite"
            s = "03"
        Case "Ohjelmisto"
            s = "04"
        Case "Verkko"
            s = "05"
        Case "Mobiililaite"
            s = "06"
        Case "Tarvikkeet"
            s = "07"
        Case "Palvelu"
            s = "08"
    End Select

    Select Case Range("b2")
        Case "Kannettavat"
            s2 = "1"
        Case "Poytakoneet"
            s2 = "2"
        Case "Kaytetyt"
            s2 = "3"
    End Select

    Select Case Range("c2")
        Case "_13"
            s3 = "1"
        Case "_14"
            s3 = "2"
        Case "_15.6"
            s3 = "3"
        Case "_17"
            s3 = "4"
        Case "Yrityskannettavat"
            s3 = "5"
    End Select
    Select Case Range("d2")
        Case "Acer"
            s4 = "1"
        Case "Apple"
            s4 = "2"
        Case "ASUS"
            s4 = "3"
        Case "Fujitsu"
            s4 = "4"
        Case "HP"
            s4 = "5"
        Case "Lenovo"
            s4 = "6"
        Case "Samsung"
            s4 = "7"
    End Select

    s = s & s2 & s3 & s4
    Set rngDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngDB, s & "*") + 1
    s = s & Format(n, "0000")
    Set rngT = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set rngT = rngT.Offset(1, 0)
    rngT = s

End Sub
```

Result Image

[image]

Comment: I changed  s = s & s2 & s4 & s4 to  s = s & s2 & s3 & s4 and it works perfectly! It also worked as I added more "Cases". Thank you so much! This code is easy enough for me to understand and use as an excel newbie.

Comment: @Zymymenestys, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping I've understood this as your question is a bit vague (I should have probably asked first....)

Anyway, your code written in it's current form will quickly become very unmanageable. Personally, I'd keep my key and code pairs in separate tables and reference them in my VBA to generate a `Dictionary` but in this example I've produced them inline. I've rewritten your procedures as a `Function` as well so that I can reference them in a master `Sub`. You will probably have to update with your sheet references/Ranges but I've tried to infer them as best as possible.

On `Sheet1` I have my inputs selected in `Row` 2. Once the inputs have been selected, call the `Sub` `GenerateSKU`. This will firstly generate a Prefix dependent on the inputs. It will then find all SKUs that have the same prefix and increment the last 4 digits by 1. It will then append a new SKU onto the end of your list of SKUs in `Sheet2` and display a `MsgBox` with the new SKU.

Similarly, These can be decoded by selecting a SKU and running the `DecodeSKU` sub

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GenerateSKU()
    Dim ExistingSKU As Range
    Dim MaxExistingSKUNum As Long, LastSKU As Long
    Dim firstExistingSKUAddress As String, NewSKU As String, SKU As String, SKUPreFix As String

    With Sheet1
        SKUPreFix = EncodeKopioi(1, .Range("A2").Value2) & _
                    EncodeKopioi(2, .Range("B2").Value2) & _
                    EncodeKopioi(3, .Range("C2").Value2) & _
                    EncodeKopioi(4, .Range("D2").Value2)
    End With

    With Sheet2
        With .Range("A:A")
            Set ExistingSKU = .Find(what:=SKUPreFix, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not ExistingSKU Is Nothing Then
                firstExistingSKUAddress = ExistingSKU.Address
                Do
                    If Left(ExistingSKU.Value2, 5) = SKUPreFix And MaxExistingSKUNum < Val(Right(ExistingSKU.Value2, 4)) Then
                        MaxExistingSKUNum = Val(Right(ExistingSKU.Value2, 4))
                    End If
                    Set ExistingSKU = .FindNext(ExistingSKU)
                Loop Until ExistingSKU Is Nothing Or ExistingSKU.Address = firstExistingSKUAddress
            End If
        End With
        NewSKU = SKUPreFix & Format(MaxExistingSKUNum + 1, "0000")
        LastSKU = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(LastSKU + 1, 1).Value2 = NewSKU
    End With

    MsgBox NewSKU
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub DecodeSKU()
    With ActiveCell
        MsgBox EncodeKopioi(1, .Value2, True) & vbNewLine & _
               EncodeKopioi(2, .Value2, True) & vbNewLine & _
               EncodeKopioi(3, .Value2, True) & vbNewLine & _
               EncodeKopioi(4, .Value2, True)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function EncodeKopioi(KopioiNum As Long, str As String, Optional Decode As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim KopioiDict As Object: Set KopioiDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim MidStart As Long, MidLen As Long
    Dim key
    Select Case KopioiNum
        Case 1
            MidStart = 1
            MidLen = 2
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Tietokoneet", Item:="01"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Komponentit", Item:="02"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Oheislaite", Item:="03"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Ohjelmisto", Item:="04"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Verkko", Item:="05"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Mobiililaite", Item:="06"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Tarvikkeet", Item:="07"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Palvelu", Item:="08"
        Case 2
            MidStart = 3
            MidLen = 1
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Kannettavat", Item:="1"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Pöytäkoneet", Item:="2"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Käytetyt", Item:="3"
        Case 3
            MidStart = 4
            MidLen = 1
            KopioiDict.Add key:="_13", Item:="1"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="_14", Item:="2"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="_15.6", Item:="3"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="_17", Item:="4"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Yrityskannettavat", Item:="5"
        Case 4
            MidStart = 5
            MidLen = 1
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Acer", Item:="1"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Apple", Item:="2"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Asus", Item:="3"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Fujitsu", Item:="4"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="HP", Item:="5"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Lenovo", Item:="6"
            KopioiDict.Add key:="Samsung", Item:="7"
        Case Else
            Err.Raise Number:="9998", _
                      Source:="EncodeKopioi", _
                      Description:="Invalid KopioiNum"
    End Select

    If Decode = True Then
        For Each key In KopioiDict
            If KopioiDict(key) = Mid(str, MidStart, MidLen) Then
                EncodeKopioi = key
                Exit For
            End If
        Next key
    Else
        EncodeKopioi = KopioiDict(str)
    End If

    If EncodeKopioi = vbNullString Then
        Err.Raise Number:=9999, _
                  Source:="EncodeKopioi", _
                  Description:="Failed to " & IIf(Decode = False, "En", "De") & "code for " & IIf(Decode = False, "input ", "SKU ") & str
    End If
End Function
```